# Check if string is valid Date

Tags: c#, validation, datetime

I want to check if a string is a valid DateTime, but am having some trouble. First off, I know about `DateTime.TryParse` and I can't use it because it requires a `DateTime` as an `out` parameter, and I don't have one available.

I have a class that has 2 public properties, `Name` and `DOB`. I am able to update these properties of an individual `Person` with a button click. So I thought that in my Button's `Click` event, I would check first if the string being passed is a valid `DateTime`:

```
private void Button_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listBoxPeople.SelectedIndex != -1 && DateTime.TryParse(textBoxDOB.Text, out new DateTime()))
    {
        Person p = listBoxPeople.SelectedItem as Person;
        p.Name = textBoxName.Text;
        p.DOB = DateTime.Parse(textBoxDOB.Text);
    }
}
```

However, that doens't work, it throws an error saying the `out` parameter must be assignable.

So I tried just using `TryParse` and making the `out` parameter the `DOB` property of the object, like so:

```
private void Button_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listBoxPeople.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        Person p = listBoxPeople.SelectedItem as Person;
        p.Name = textBoxName.Text;
        DateTime.TryParse(textBoxDOB.Text, out p.DOB);
    }
}
```

But that also throws an error, saying that

> A property cannot be passed as an out or ref parameter

Is there a function hidden somewhere that just returns a bool of whether a string is a valid `DateTime`, without requiring any `out` parameters?

Comment: *First off, I know about DateTime.TryParse and I can't use it because it requires a DateTime as an out parameter, and I don't have one available.* And you can't just make one because...?

Comment: @Tyress I can, but I'd rather not, please don't downvote.

Comment: @Tyress acutally was about to ask the same thing ...

Comment: I suggest you **learn c#** before you go any further

Comment: @user3189142 reason for downvote (as its label say): "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" ... well, where should I start without being a SO nazi ...

Comment: So I can't even ask a simple question about a 1 line way of determining if a string is a valid Date... *sigh*

Comment: If you don't want to use c# builtin features, you can always try a regexp.

Comment: @user3189142 Well, I didn't downvote yet, but just make one maybe? C# 6.0 will allow you to make an out var on the fly using TryParse (and thus fulfill your one-line dream). Until then you can't.

Comment: @user3189142 The thing is: please think about your issue for one second before throwing it up on SO, do a google-search before, read the manual, put some effort in research. This is one of the *obvious* questions, and thus, at least to me, not useful at all ... But there's the community, and if there's one thinking "This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear", (s)he'll upvote ...

Comment: @user3189142 btw, you could simply go for either a local variable or a field (which can be used for `ref`/`out` stuff in contrast to a property)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
private void Button_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime tempDate;
    if (listBoxPeople.SelectedIndex != -1 && DateTime.TryParse(textBoxDOB.Text, out tempDate))
    {
        Person p = listBoxPeople.SelectedItem as Person;
        p.Name = textBoxName.Text;
        p.DOB = tempDate;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following

```
DateTime.ParseExact(textBoxDOB.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

instead of

```
DateTime.TryParse(textBoxDOB.Text, out new DateTime())
```

Comment: -, which will throw an exception if parsing fails - so the whole stack goes down ... and `ParseExact` does not return `bool`, so please elaborate on how to `ParseExact` in this very context.